# cannot import name "Youtube"?

Tags: python, pytube

I need help, I got stuck with a problem inside of my python code.
I have installed pytube module from cmd with
`pip install pytube` and got "succesfully installed", also installed `pip install pytube3`, vs code doesnt find any error in the debbuging but when I try to run my code I got this error:

```
File "c:\Users\redos\OneDrive\Desktop\Progetti\Programmazione\Python\progetti\youtube.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pytube import Youtube, Search
ImportError: cannot import name 'Youtube' from 'pytube' (C:\Users\redos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytube\__init__.py)
```

I also tried to do `pip install pytube3 --upgrade` and `pip install pytube --upgrade` and got

```
Requirement already satisfied: pytube3 in c:\users\redos\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (9.6.4)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in c:\users\redos\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pytube3) (3.10.0.0)
```

this is the code:

```
from pytube import Youtube, Search
 
print("================================\n What do you want to do?: ")
 
availableChoose = [
    '1 Search videos', 
    '...', 
    '================================'
]
 
for choose in availableChoose:
    print(choose)
 
userChoose = input()
 
userChoose = userChoose.lower()
 
def videoSearch():
    userSearch = input("Enter the title of the video you want to search: ")
    vid = Search(userSearch)
    availableResults = len(vid.results)
    strAvailableResults = str(availableResults)
    print("The available results are " + strAvailableResults)
    vidResultsList = vid.results
    vidResultsList = str(vidResultsList)
    vidResultsList = vidResultsList.replace("<pytube.__main__.YouTube object: videoId=", "")
    vidResultsList = vidResultsList.replace(">", "")
    vidResultsList = vidResultsList.replace("[", "")
    vidResultsList = vidResultsList.replace("]", "")
    vidResultsList = vidResultsList.replace(" ", "")
    vidResultsList = vidResultsList.split(',')
    for vidResultsObject in vidResultsList:
        vidTempObject = ("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + vidResultsObject)
        vidTempObject2 = Youtube(vidTempObject)
        print(vidTempObject2.title)
        
if(userChoose == "search" or userChoose == "search video" or userChoose == "search videos" or userChoose == "1"):
    videoSearch()
```

Comment: `YouTube` instead of `Youtube`, python is capitalization specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `YouTube` instead of `Youtube`. Capitalize the **t** in **Youtube**. Like this...

```
from pytube import YouTube, Search
```

Comment: oh my god I dont know why I didnt find that out before...sorry and thank you for answer

Comment: No problem. If your problem was solved then maybe you can accept this answer :-)